# On duplicate, key update error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get this error when "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" I want to just update the email if it exists in the database...

```
{
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO  '._DB_PREFIX_.'newsletter (id_shop, id_shop_group, email, newsletter_date_add, ip_registration_newsletter, http_referer, active)
                VALUES
                ('.$this->context->shop->id.',
                '.$this->context->shop->id_shop_group.',
                \''.pSQL($email).'\',
                NOW(),
                \''.pSQL(Tools::getRemoteAddr()).'\',
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                email='$email',
                (
                    SELECT c.http_referer
                    FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'connections c
                    WHERE c.id_guest = '.(int)$this->context->customer->id.'
                    ORDER BY c.date_add DESC LIMIT 1
                ),
                '.(int)$active.'
                ) 
                        ';

        return Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
    }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE. That means you have a variable in your code that is unexpected. It probably even tells you what line number in that error you pasted. You should follow that.

Comment: This is a PHP syntax error, usually caused by a missing semi-colon.  The error message should give you a line number.  Look at the line, and see if the line above it is missing a semi-colon.

Comment: in fact it specifically looks like it's this line right here... email='$email', should be email=\''.$email.'\',

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some periods, which is causing the parser to flip out. Change this:

```
email='$email',
```

to this:

```
email="'.$email.'",
```

That said, you should not build a query by simply concatenating strings like this; it opens you up to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You should use MySQLi or PDO and use prepared statements to prevent injection.

Comment: correct about missing periods, however since email is a string it needs to be encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

```
email='$email',
```

should be:

```
email=\''.$email.'\',
```